# Unable to access mutator functions in Wizard form page while using react-final-form

Tags: react-final-form

I am trying to create a Wizard form using react-final-form by referring to this code https://codesandbox.io/s/km2n35kq3v. For my use case I need some mutator functions to be used inside my form fields. This example illustrates how to do that - https://codesandbox.io/s/kx8qv67nk5?from-embed.
I am not sure how to access mutator functions in my form steps when I am using a wizard form instead of a single page form.

I tried to combine both the examples by modifying the `<Form>` component rendered by Wizard.js to pass in the mutators. However I cannot access these mutators in the Wizard form pages.

In Wizard.js

```
    return (
      <Form
        mutators={{
          // potentially other mutators could be merged here
          ...arrayMutators,
        }}
        render={({
          handleSubmit,
          submitting,
          values,
          pristine,
          invalid,
          form: {
            mutators: {push, pop, remove},
          },
        }) => {
          return (
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
```

Another file index.js

```
    <Wizard
      initialValues={{ employed: true, stooge: "larry" }}
      onSubmit={onSubmit}
    >
      <Wizard.Page>
        <FieldArray name="customers">
          {({ fields }) =>
            fields.map((name, index) => (
              <div key={name}>
                <label>Cust. #{index + 1}</label>

                <Field
                  name={`${name}.firstName`}
                  component="input"
                  placeholder="First Name"
                />
                <span
                  onClick={() => fields.remove(index)}
                  style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
                >
                  ❌
                </span>
              </div>
            ))
          }
        </FieldArray>
      </Wizard.Page>
</Wizard>
```

It errors out - remove is undefined in index.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/znzlqvzvnx

changes I have made:

Wizard.js

```js
     static Page = ({ children, mutators }) => {
        if(typeof children === 'function'){
          return children(mutators);
        }

        return children;
      };

     ...

     <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
       {
          // activePage
          <activePage.type {...activePage.props} mutators={mutators} />
       }

     ...
```

index.js (only first `<Wizard.page>`)

```js
      <Wizard.Page>
        {
          ({ upper }) => (
            <React.Fragment>
              <div>
                <label>First Name</label>
                <Field
                  name="firstName"
                  component="input"

                  ...

              </div>
            </React.Fragment>
          )
        }        
      </Wizard.Page>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. I tried following this example, however it does not works for custom mutator functions instead of fieldArray mutators. For example I tried using an 'upper' mutator function in this example - https://codesandbox.io/s/v6my448l1y.